# In tensorflow, how to use tf.where() on y to select rows from x where x and y have different shapes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a matrix of size x = 32x512 and a label vector of size y = 32x1. Labels are in the range 0-3. I need to select rows from x who have label 1 in the corresponding y.

I tried using the following command:
temp_maps = tf.where( tf.equal(y,1) , x , tf.math.scalar_mul(0,x) )
but this gives me this error:

**ValueError: Dimenstions must be equal, but are 32 and 512 for op:SelectV2 with input shapes: [32] , [32,512] , [32,512]**

What I want is the rows from x whose labels are 1 in y. I am using tf.math.scalar_mul(0,x) because on condition false something has to be selected so I am selecting a zero tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dummy matrices:

```
        import tensorflow as tf
        tf.enable_eager_execution()
        import numpy as np
        B = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(0, 3, 32).reshape((32, 1)))
        A = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(32*512).reshape((32, 512)))
```

Use `tf.equal` to get boolean tensor for all 2-labels:

```
    eq = tf.equal(B, 2)
    In [16]: print(eq)
    tf.Tensor(
    [[ True]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [ True]
     [ True]
     [False]
     [ True]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [ True]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [False]
     [ True]
     [False]
     [ True]
     [False]
     [False]
     [ True]
     [False]
     [False]], shape=(32, 1), dtype=bool)
```

Now you could use `tf.where` to get positional indices:

```
In [19]: tf.where(eq)
Out[19]: 
<tf.Tensor: id=45, shape=(8, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 9,  0],
       [10,  0],
       [12,  0],
       [18,  0],
       [24,  0],
       [26,  0],
       [29,  0]])>
```

If you would like to get a slice of A you could use `tf.gather`:

```
In [30]: tf.gather(A, tf.where(tf.equal(B, 2))[:, 0])
Out[30]: 
<tf.Tensor: id=105, shape=(8, 512), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[    0,     1,     2, ...,   509,   510,   511],
       [ 4608,  4609,  4610, ...,  5117,  5118,  5119],
       [ 5120,  5121,  5122, ...,  5629,  5630,  5631],
       ...,
       [12288, 12289, 12290, ..., 12797, 12798, 12799],
       [13312, 13313, 13314, ..., 13821, 13822, 13823],
       [14848, 14849, 14850, ..., 15357, 15358, 15359]])>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the accepted answer is valid, since this is a) memory inefficient b) graph execution incompatible approach.

Since I've been struggling with the same issue I had to find a way how to overcome the issue:

```py
tf.where( tf.expand_dims(tf.equal(y,1), 1) , x , tf.math.scalar_mul(0,x) )
```

hence the first bool tensor becomes of shape [32, 1], which is broadcastable to [32,512].